# shap.force_plot raises "In v0.20 force_plot now requires the base value as the first parameter!"

Tags: python, shap

I want to learn how to use SHAP and found this notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/code/joshuaswords/predicting-a-stroke-shap-lime-explainer-eli5

Now I want to use shap.force_plot.
For that I inserted the following code after In [50]:

```
shap.initjs()
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0]  ,X_test.iloc[0])
```

But all it does is raising the following Exception:
"In v0.20 force_plot now requires the base value as the first parameter!"

Comment: Likely the API changed, so check the current documentation.